# Forcing timeit to automatically choose number of times statement is executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeit

In the command line, I can do:

```
python -m timeit 'a = 1'
```

According to the docs:

> If -n is not given, a suitable number of loops is calculated by trying successive powers
>   of 10 until the total time is at least 0.2 seconds.

This works great, but how can I get the same behavior when using `timeit` in my program? If I leave out the `number` argument to the `timeit.timeit` call, it will simply default to `1000000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs don't make it obvious that there exists such functionality, I'll assume there isn't. Fortunately, defining a wrapper that does it for you is isn't too hard:

```
import timeit

def auto_timeit(stmt='pass', setup='pass'):
    n = 1
    t = timeit.timeit(stmt, setup, number=n)

    while t < 0.2:
        n *= 10
        t = timeit.timeit(stmt, setup, number=n)

    return t / n # normalise to time-per-run
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to writing a wrapper:

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.call([sys.executable, '-m', 'timeit', stmt])
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? I don't see any obvious problems with it.